# Escaped characters showing up incorrectly

Tags: packages, font-encodings

I'm using the SIGCHI (https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats) conference paper template in LaTeX. That template includes the package:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This package, however, is causing a very bizarre issue though: many characters that must be escaped aren't appearing properly. For example:

`\_` shows up as  ̇

`\{` shows up as –

`\}` shows up as  ̋

So I'm trying to have the authors' email list, written as

```
\{author1,author2,another\_author\}@university.edu
```

which should look like

> {author1,author2,another_author}@university.edu

but instead it's appearing as

> –author1,author2,another ̇author ̋@university.edu

and I cannot figure out how to fix it. If I don't include that package, it works fine. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately the `sigchi` class is written in the worst possible way with respect to fonts. So it can be expected it doesn't work with font encoding dependent commands. `:(` Try removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @egreg Not its only problem... :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rant

I'm really surprised that a template based on the `sigchi` class recommends usage of the `T1` font enconding, because the class contains

```
\newfont{\aufnt}{ptmb7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
```

together with several ***absurd*** font declarations of the same kind. Since it also does

```
{\baselineskip 16pt\aufnt   % each author set in \12 pt Arial, in a
 \lineskip .5em             % tabular environment
 \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author
 \end{tabular}\par}
```

when processing `\maketitle`, there is ***no*** hope whatsoever that T1 specific commands such as `\{` can work in the context of an author. The same holds for the title and also for sectional titles.

Using `\newfont` 20 years after the release of LaTeX2e has no justification whatsoever; it would be very easy to change the font setup in a compatible way. The maintainers of the class don't want to do it, but doing so they make it impossible for authors to title their sections as they'd like. Polish or Vietnamese authors will not be able to print their names properly, because OT1 encoded fonts don't support the needed accented characters.

Just to prove what I'm saying, here's the complete set of font definitions:

```
% -- Start of block C -- METAFONT (modern usage)
% +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% Next (default) block for those using Metafont
% Andrew Duchowski 06/19/2006
% *** THIS BLOCK FOR THOSE USING METAFONT *****
% *********************************************
% notes: 7t fonts are 7-bit latex, 8t fonts are T1 fonts
\newfont{\secfnt}{phvb7t at 9pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\secit}{phvbo7t at 9pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\subsecfnt}{phvro7t at 9pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\subsecit}{phvr7t at 9pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\ttlfnt}{phvb7t at 18pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\ttlit}{phvbo7t at 18pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\subttlfnt}{phvr7t at 14pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\subttlit}{phvro7t at 14pt}                     % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\subttlbf}{phvb7t at 14pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\aufnt}{ptmb7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\auit}{ptmbo7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\affaddr}{ptmr7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\affaddrit}{ptmro7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\eaddfnt}{ptmr7t at 12pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\ixpt}{ptmr7t at 10pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\confname}{ptmri7t at 8pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\crnotice}{ptmr7t at 8pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
\newfont{\ninept}{ptmr7t at 10pt}                    % 05-16-2006 atd
% +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% -- End of block C --
```

The “modern usage” at the start is simply ridiculous, as it has been added more than a decade after the release of LaTeX2e, with its support for font encodings. I can't understand the reference to METAFONT, which has nothing to do with these fonts.

### Solution

Remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, for the moment, and mail the class maintainers each day so that they eventually realize there are slightly better methods for setting fonts than relying on methods deprecated 20 years ago.